# Questions within questions within questions

Tags: discussion, questions

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Exit strategies for “chameleon questions”](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/43478/exit-strategies-for-chameleon-questions)

What I don't understand are people trying to get MORE than they asked for.

Sometimes I have to answer 6 questions before  I get the OP to mark my solution as correct. When is time to MOVE ON and when is it time to ask more and more questions within a question?

Comment: I usually answer the follow-up questions, because my main objective is helping others. However, if the OP keeps asking trivial/vague/incomplete questions, I don't bother composing yet another comment.